React Native Sip 415 Status Code Error Unsupported Media
I want to make a call using the React native sip library, we handle the call through the backend, I make a call, I answer, but when I answer the call on the mobile application again, I get a 415 error.
My Create Account Function;
export const createSipAccount = async () => {
  let configuration = {
    name: 'xxxx',
    username: 'xxxx',
    domain: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    regOnAdd: true,
    proxy: null,
    transport: 'TCP',
    regServer: null,
    regTimeout: 600,
    contactUriParams: ';im-type=sip',
  };

  try {
    const account = await endpoint.createAccount(configuration);
    console.log('Account created', account);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('SIP hesabı oluşturulurken bir hata oluştu:', error);
  }
};

Start Sip Function
export const startSipConnection = async () => {
  endpoint = new Endpoint();

  try {
    const state = await endpoint.start({
      service: {
        ua: 'RNSIP Android',
      },
      network: {
        useWifi: true,
        useOtherNetworks: true,
      },
    });

    console.log(state);

    endpoint.on('registration_changed', account => {
      console.log('registration_changed', account);
    });
    endpoint.on('connectivity_changed', online => {
      console.log(online, 'changed');
    });
    endpoint.on('call_received', call => {
      playSound();
      callStat = call;
      alert('arama cevaplandi', call);
    });
    endpoint.on('call_changed', call => {
      console.log('callChanged', call);
    });
    endpoint.on('call_terminated', call => {
      console.log('kapandı', call);
    });
    endpoint.on('call_screen_locked', call => {});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('SIP bağlantısı başlatılırken bir hata oluştu:', error);
  }
};

this my account
{
  "_data": {
    "contactUriParams": ";im-type=sip",
    "domain": "xxxx",
    "id": 0,
    "name": "xxxx",
    "password": "xxxx",
    "regOnAdd": true,
    "regTimeout": "600",
    "registration": {
      "active": true,
      "reason": "OK",
      "status": 200,
      "statusText": "OK"
    },
    "transport": "TCP",
    "uri": "xxxxx <sip:2776@xxxxx>",
    "username": "xxxx"
  },
  "_registration": {
    "_active": true,
    "_reason": "OK",
    "_status": 200,
    "_statusText": "OK"
  }
}

I make a call, the phone rings but when I answer I get this 415 status code unsupported media error
 {
  "_accountId": 0,
  "_audioCount": 1,
  "_callId": "SwTPRlckuSeXXL7VCOEsYw..",
  "_connectDuration": 0,
  "_constructionTime": 1716981892,
  "_held": false,
  "_id": 1,
  "_lastReason": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "_lastStatusCode": 415,
  "_localContact": "<sip:xxx@31.223.49.122:10535;transport=TCP;im-type=sip;ob>",
  "_localUri": "<sip:xxx@10.34.42.46>",
  "_media": [],
  "_muted": false,
  "_provisionalMedia": [],
  "_remoteAudioCount": 0,
  "_remoteContact": "<sip:xxx@xxx:5060;transport=TCP>",
  "_remoteName": "xxxx",
  "_remoteNumber": "xxxx",
  "_remoteOfferer": false,
  "_remoteUri": "\"xxxx\" <sip:xxxx@xxxx>",
  "_remoteVideoCount": 0,
  "_speaker": false,
  "_state": 6,
  "_stateText": "DISCONNECTED",
  "_totalDuration": 2,
  "_videoCount": 1
}

